# Function multiplying two polynomials gives wrong result

Tags: python, polynomials

I want to create a function called `multipoly(x,y)` which takes two lists as input, multiplies the lists and returns the answers.

Polynomial is represented as follows: for instance x^4+2X^3 is represented as `[(1,4),(2,3)]`.
Here is something I get but it returns wrong answer for some test cases:

```
def multipoly(p1,p2):
    x=max(p1,p2)
    y=min(p1,p2)
    p1=x
    p2=y
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for item in p2:
            p1[i] = ((p1[i][0] * item[0]), (p1[i][1] + item[1]))
            p2.remove(item)
    return p1
print(multipoly([(1,1),(-1,0)],[(1,2),(1,1),(1,0)]))
```

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? NumPy has a Polynomial module: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html. Also, take a look at SymPy: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off to implement this as a class to encapsulate all the operations on a polynomial:

maybe something like this as a basis to start?

Here, I chose to **represent the polynomial via a sequence of coefficients where the indices are the corresponding exponents of `x`**

Caveat, the results look okay, but I did not write tests, so it may be brittle on some corner cases.

```
class Polynomial:

    def __init__(self, coefficients:list):
        """represents polynomials as a list of parameters where
        the indices are the exponents"""
        self.coefficients = coefficients

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.coefficients)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.coefficients[idx]

    def __iter__(self):
        for coeff in self.coefficients:
            yield coeff

    def __str__(self):
        res = [str(self.coefficients[0]) + ' + '] if self.coefficients[0] != 0 else []
        for exponent, coeff in enumerate(self.coefficients[1:]):
            e = exponent + 1
            if coeff != 0:
                if e == 1:
                    if coeff == 1:
                        res.append('x + ')
                    else:
                        res.append(f'({coeff})*x + ')
                elif coeff == 1:
                    res.append(f'x**{e} + ')
                else:
                    res.append(f'({coeff})*x**{e} + ')
        return ''.join(res)[:-3]

    def __add__(self, other):
        result = [0] * max(len(self), len(other))
        for idx in range(len(result)):
            try:
                a = self[idx]
            except IndexError:
                a = 0
            try:
                b = other[idx]
            except IndexError:
                b = 0
            result[idx] = a + b
        return Polynomial(result)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        result = [0] * (len(self) + len(other))
        for exponent_a, coeff_a in enumerate(self):
            for exponent_b, coeff_b in enumerate(other):
                result[exponent_a + exponent_b] += coeff_a * coeff_b
        return Polynomial(result)

    def d_dx(self):
        return Polynomial([expo * coeff for expo, coeff in enumerate(self)][1:])


a = Polynomial([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6])
b = Polynomial([1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0])
print(a, '\n', b, '\n', a + b, '\n', a * b, '\n', a.d_dx(), '\n', b.d_dx(), '\n', (a*b).d_dx())
print()
c = Polynomial([1, 1])
d = Polynomial([1, -1])
print(c, '\n', d, '\n', c + d, '\n', c * d)
```

#### output:

```
1 + (2)*x + (3)*x**2 + (6)*x**5 
 1 + (2)*x + (3)*x**2 + x**3 + x**4 
 2 + (4)*x + (6)*x**2 + x**3 + x**4 + (6)*x**5 
 1 + (4)*x + (10)*x**2 + (13)*x**3 + (12)*x**4 + (11)*x**5 + (15)*x**6 + (18)*x**7 + (6)*x**8 + (6)*x**9 
 2 + (6)*x + (30)*x**4 
 2 + (6)*x + (3)*x**2 + (4)*x**3
 4 + (20)*x + (39)*x**2 + (48)*x**3 + (55)*x**4 + (90)*x**5 + (126)*x**6 + (48)*x**7 + (54)*x**8

1 + x 
 1 + (-1)*x 
 2 
 1 + (-1)*x**2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store the result of the multiplication ,So that the exponents which are already calculated can directly be added to the previous calculated value

The following code works

```
def multipoly(p1,p2):
    mul = dict()
    for m in p1:
        for n in p2:
            if m[1] + n[1] in mul:
                mul[m[1] + n[1]] += m[0] * n[0]
            else:
                mul[m[1] + n[1]] = m[0] * n[0]
    m_res = []
    for p, q in mul.items():
        m_res.append((q, p))
    return m_res
print(multipoly([(1,1),(-1,0)],[(1,2),(1,1),(1,0)]))
```

It takes less than your solution. Because in your solution you are removing an element in p2 which takes `O(sizeof(p2))` time.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way. Using itertools groupby to combine similar terms:

```
from itertools import groupby
def multipoly(poly1,poly2):
    #multiply two polynolials
    temp = [(p1[0]*p2[0], p1[1]+p2[1]) for p1 in poly1 for p2 in poly2]

    #sort to use for groupby
    temp = sorted(temp, key= lambda x: x[1])   
    #groupby second term
    g = groupby(temp, lambda x: x[1])

    #combine terms
    result = []
    for k,v in g:
        result.append((sum([i[0] for i in v]), k))
    result.sort(key=lambda x: -x[1])
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a function to multiply two polynomials, represented as a list of tuples `[(coef, expn) ...]` you can start by multiplying term by term the two polynomials `p1, p2` like this

```
p3 = [(c1*c2, e1+e2) for c1, e1 in p1 for c2, e2 in p2]
```

but you have a problem because, in general, you will have more than one term with the same exponent, to *normalize* the result in `p3` we can use a dictionary

```
d = {}
for c, e in p3:
    d[e] = d.get(e, 0) + c
```

note that `d.get(e, 0)` returns `d[e]` if the exponent is already present in `d` or returns `0`.

Finally, you want back your results as a list of tuples

```
p3 = [(c, e) for e, c in d.items()]
```

but this list is not guaranteed to be sorted in order of decreasing exponent

```
p3 = sorted(p3, key=lambda t: -t[1])
```

It is possible to put all this in a single callable

```
def pmult(p1, p2):
     d = {}
     for coef, expn in [(c1*c2, e1+e2) for c1, e1 in p1 for c2, e2 in p2]:
         d[expn] = d.get(expn,0)+coef
     return sorted([(c, e) for e, c in d.items()], key=lambda t: -t[1])
```

A test:

```
In [25]: a = [(1,2),(3,0)]
In [26]: b = [(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1),(5,0)]
In [27]: def pmult(p1, p2):
    ...:     d = {}
    ...:     for coef, expn in [(c1*c2, e1+e2) for c1, e1 in p1 for c2, e2 in p2]:
    ...:         d[expn] = d.get(expn,0)+coef
    ...:     return sorted([(c, e) for e, c in d.items()], key=lambda t: -t[1])
In [28]: pmult(a, b)
Out[28]: [(1, 6), (2, 5), (6, 4), (10, 3), (14, 2), (12, 1), (15, 0)]
```